# Script return blank just in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've got very frustrating problem. I send AJAX request to PHP file and when I see Chrome Network Tools, it donť return any JSON. But when I try post the same data via POSTMAN tool in Chrome, it return right. When I open script normally, it return right. Just when I sen request via AJAXm it return nothing.

This is my PHP file: (I know it's functionally useless at this time, i need fix this error before it can do what I need)

```
$stav = 2;
$ret = array();
$name = query_r("select * from users where username = 'admin'");

$ret['stav']=$stav;

$json = json_encode($ret);
echo $json;
```

At line 3 must be problem, because when I put it out, it works. But function is 100% exist, 'cause when i put nonsense name of function, it write an error. DB query is also right, i tried it in phpMyAdmin console.

This is my AJAX request:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../admin/scripts/login.php",
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (vysledek){
              if(vysledek.stav===1){
                window.location.href("../index.php")  
              }
              else if(vysledek.stav===2){
                alertify.error('Špatné uživatelské jméno');
              }
              else if(vysledek.stav===3){
                alertify.error('Špatné heslo');
              }
            },
            error: function(vysledek){
              alertify.error('Vyskytla se nějaká chyba');
            }
          });  
        });
```

How I wrote, if I open PHP file in browser, it echo {"stav":2}, when I try POSTman, it echo {"stav":2}. But when I run AJAX request, it makes nothing. I really don't know what is wrong.

EDIT

Firebug:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQTfk.png)

Comment: put an `exit;` next to `echo $json;` i.e `echo $json;exit;` & then try

Comment: ajax request made in network tab?

Comment: is `query_r` is self made function? There is no such function for `PHP`

Comment: @techie_28 Still doesn't work

Comment: @uzaif When click on submit, then in network tab are information about request

Comment: do you have errors in the console ?

Comment: and what is response you got ?

Comment: @Apoorv : Yes, it is. It's like $link->query(). I tried it without selfmade function, but it didn't help.

Comment: @madalinivascu No, i haven't.

Comment: @uzaif Blank screen, nothing.

Comment: @3kolik did you do a `ctrl+F5` before running that again? what does `At line 3 must be problem, because when I put it out, it works` mean?It works fine when you comment the SQL query line?

Comment: @techie_28 Of course, still it return blank. And yes, it works fine, but in login script I need database connect. But with POSTman or in browser it works fine even with this line. Just in AJAX request it's broken,

Comment: @3kolik not sure why is this problem.try with lower case in dataType i.e `dataType: "json",` not `JSON`.

Comment: @techie_28 Still blank screen. I'm working on it for week and it's really mystery for me.

Comment: Please run that with your firebug open & attach the screenshot here.

Comment: @techie_28 I add it to main question. Hope you thought this.

Comment: are you sure the URL is correct here?your screenshot does not have a response tab in it which should have been there.

Comment: Try to `console.log(vysledek)` and then see, there can be some addional characters which json. instead of relative url try absolute for ajax request.

Comment: Check if you get any response. ***success:function(vysledek){console.log(vysledek)...}*** Open your web console, submit the form,  and see if you get a response

Comment: @techie_28 Sorry, my bad english, I propably bad understood you. Now it's reponse id EDIT of main question.

Comment: @BoazKim It's : Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: console.log(vysledek.responseText)

Comment: @BoazKim: There's nothing, it's empty.

Comment: Open your console and click on network tab. submit the form, click on the response tab see if there is any resonse

Comment: What does the third tab in your firebug(`Vyrovnavaci pamet`) has?Please post it

Comment: @BoazKim That's what I do all the time. There is no response when there is database query. When I put it out, there is {"stav":2}

Comment: @3kolik is there any `echo` statement or something in `query_r`'s body?Please post it also.

Comment: @techie_28 Nothing, it's empty.

Comment: @techie_28 It's not, there is complete query_r function :    function query_r($dotaz){
    $link = db();
    return $link->query($dotaz);
}

It's just for easier work.

Comment: PHP is the problem. Its not echoing something

Comment: @3kolik are you sure that function is running correctly?Does it fetch you the query result correctly?If there is a DB connection error or something in it that might be causing this problem

Comment: @3kolik remove `dataType:"JSON"` altogether & then check your network panel(WITH LINE 3).It should show something probably an error.

Comment: @techie_28 Yes, I'm. Now i tried fetch object from it and echo id of user in browser, without AJAX, and it works.

Comment: @techie_28 It's the same. Still empty response and still same response headers.

Comment: @3kolik can you try with using some mysql querying function like `mysqli_query` in line 3 in place of `query_r`?

Comment: @techie_28 It was one of the first things I tried. It didn't help. I use this functions in many projects and it works correctly.

Comment: It didnt help means there was no response or what?

Comment: @techie_28 Excatly, still no response.

Comment: @3kolik Well its hard to point out what is causing this..I was expecting to see something in response with `dataType:JSON` removed but you say there was nothing.

Comment: @3kolik The last thing I would try is to open the files associated with this AJAX(especially PHP files) in a different editor(`like pspad`) & then save them.Which editor are you using?Is it dreamweaver?

Comment: @techie_28 I use PSPad like default. Is possible, that can be blocked asynchronous database queries? It's propably nonsense, but i haven't other idea.

Comment: @3kolik has the file containing `query_r` correctly been included in the file where you are using it?Check the config & make server display all PHP error's.There is nothing apparent that is causing this problem & we have tried all the possibilities.

Comment: @techie_28 Function must be correct, because it works without AJAX.

Comment: @techie_28 And this same function work for me in other projects even with Ajax.

Comment: have you included the file containing `query_r` definition correctly?

Comment: can you provide a URL where we can see this?

Comment: @techie_28 Yes, that's not problem, when I use function that doesn't exists, I don't see blank in response, I see there error message.

Comment: can you give a URL where this can be seen?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try with the following code

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../admin/scripts/login.php",
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (vysledek){
              if( parseInt(vysledek.stav) == 1 ){
                window.location.href("../index.php")  
              }
              else if( parseInt(vysledek.stav) == 2 ){
                alertify.error('Špatné uživatelské jméno');
              }
              else if( parseInt(vysledek.stav) == 3 ){
                alertify.error('Špatné heslo');
              }
            },
            error: function(vysledek){
              alertify.error('Vyskytla se nějaká chyba');
            }
          });  
        });
```

Comment: Still nothing. I think it can't be in success part, because when I post, it makes error part.

Comment: is it in a live server ? can you share the url please.  can you please check by specifying the full url ajax parameter

Comment: It is. And URL must be good, because it work without line " $name = query_r("select * from users where username = 'admin'"); ". This is the line, what doesn't work in AJAX. In POSTman or browser it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$stav = 2;
$ret = array();
$name = query_r("select * from users where username = 'admin'");
$ret['stav']=$stav;

$json = json_encode($ret);
print_r($json);

?>
```

Remember to parse JSON to the response

```
...
         success: function (vysledek){
          var vysledek = (vysledek);
          if(vysledek.stav === 1){
            window.location.href("../index.php")  
          }
```

...

Comment: Thanks, but there's still no response from script.